# Declaring List inside a Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a scenario where I don't want to pass a model as an `Ienumerable` list 
to the Razor View.

```
public class School
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I need to pass the model to view as below.

```
@model Doc.Web.Models.Common.School
```

not as

```
@model IEnumerable<Doc.Web.Models.Common.School>
```

So, I decalred a List inside the same Model

```
public class School
{
    public School()
    {
        lstSchool = new List<School>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public List<School> lstSchool { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   School model= new School();
   SchoolRepository rep = new SchoolRepository();
   model.lstSchool= rep.GetData();//Read list of schools from database
   return View(model);
}
```

is this the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Why school will have a list of schools? Like parent-child hierarchies?

Comment: Formally it is correct, but semantically you might have a problem. What does your `School` class model now?

Comment: Thats fine.You have to enumerate the list of the values using Model.lstSchool in your view to get the values.

Comment: Your class called "School" is acutally a list of schools? You could rename your class Schools or SchoolList then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why do you want to pass `@model Doc.Web.Models.Common.School` to the view ? where you need a "list" on your view.

Here is something you can try...

**Class structure :** Create a SchoolList class

```
public class School
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolList 
{
    public List<School> Schools { get; set; }
}
```

**Pass to view :**

```
@model Doc.Web.Models.Common.SchoolList
```

**Controller :**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SchoolList model= new SchoolList();
    SchoolRepository rep = new SchoolRepository();

    //Read list of schools from database
    model.Schools = rep.GetData(); 

    return View(model);
}
```

So this way you don't need to pass an IEnumerable to the view and get the job done.